# Metodo Entry em do tkinter, Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu estava tentando pegar uma o valor numérico do método `Entry`, eu pego ele, com o `get()`, mas ao transformar para `float` ou `int`, dependendo do lugar onde esta ele me retorna um erro. Da maneira que esta funciona, direitinho, mas eu gostaria de entender, por qual motivo da erro se eu tentar converter para um `float` ou `int`, logo abaixo da `entry`, ex no código abaixo, onde esta comentad`(teste3 = float(teste2))`, nesse local da erro, porém se eu chamar a função no `ttk.Bunton`, não da erro.

esse é o erro que dá:

> ```
> teste3 = float(teste2) ValueError: could not convert string to float:
> ```

Código:

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import ttk

def imprime():

    valor2 = valor.get()

    valor2 = float(valor2)


win = tk.Tk()
   
   
win.title("Calculadora Simples")

label = ttk.Label(win, text="digite um numero")

label.grid(column=0, row=0)


valor = ttk.Entry(win)

valor.grid(column=1, row=0)

teste2 = valor.get()

#===========================================
#teste3 = float(teste2)
#===========================================

action = ttk.Button(win, text="Click me", command=imprime)

action.grid(column=1, row=1)
#=====================
# Start GUI
#=====================
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre pois o retorno do `valor.get()` é vazio, logo ao tentar converter vazio para float, você tem o erro de conversão, é possível simular essa mesma situação com o código abaixo:

```
valor = float("")
```

Você pode converter o valor, somente caso o get retorno algo, fazendo um if simples:

```
if teste2:
    teste3 = float(teste2)
else:
    teste3 = 0
```

Porém fique atento, nem todo valor pode ser convertido para float, se o usuário digitar letras no seu Entry, ao clicar no botão também será gerado um erro.

Nesse caso, uma opção é verificar a exceção durante a conversão:

```
try:
  valor = float("A")
except ValueError:
  valor = 0

print(valor)
```

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado!